# Does offer make the coroutines close or cancelled?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I was looking at the flow documentation on the Android Developer site and I have a question.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#callback

If you look at the above link, you will see code like this.

```kotlin
class FirestoreUserEventsDataSource(
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore
) {
    // Method to get user events from the Firestore database
    fun getUserEvents(): Flow<UserEvents> = callbackFlow {

        // Reference to use in Firestore
        var eventsCollection: CollectionReference? = null
        try {
            eventsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("collection")
                .document("app")
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            // If Firebase cannot be initialized, close the stream of data
            // flow consumers will stop collecting and the coroutine will resume
            close(e)
        }

        // Registers callback to firestore, which will be called on new events
        val subscription = eventsCollection?.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ ->
            if (snapshot == null) { return@addSnapshotListener }
            // Sends events to the flow! Consumers will get the new events
            try {
                offer(snapshot.getEvents())
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                // Event couldn't be sent to the flow
            }
        }

        // The callback inside awaitClose will be executed when the flow is
        // either closed or cancelled.
        // In this case, remove the callback from Firestore
        awaitClose { subscription?.remove() }
    }
}
```

In the code above, `awaitClose` is explained to be executed when the coroutine is closed or cancelled.

But, there is no `close()` in the code except for the try-catch statement that initializes the `eventsCollection`.

Additionally, says `offer does not add the element to the channel and **returns false** immediately` at the bottom of the Android Developer page.

My question is, in the code above, when `offer(snapshot.getEvents())` is executed, does the coroutine cancel with `return false`, so `awaitClose` is executed?

Comment: `Offer` is deprecated and should be changed with `trySend`

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for telling me! So, is it correct that `trySend` cancels the coroutine with `return false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expectation:**

As the documentation says:

> When you try to add a new element to a full channel, `send` **suspends** the
> producer until there's space for the new element, whereas `offer` does
> not add the element to the channel and returns `false` immediately.

**Ergo:**

It Immediately adds the specified element to this channel, if this doesn’t violate its capacity restrictions, and returns the successful result. Otherwise, returns failed or closed result. This is synchronous variant of send, which backs off in situations when send suspends or throws.

So when `trySend` call returns a non-successful result, it guarantees that the element was not delivered to the consumer, and it does not call `onUndeliveredElement` that was installed for this channel. See “[Undelivered elements](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html)” section in Channel documentation for details on handling undelivered elements.

**Conclusion:**

A typical usage for `onDeliveredElement` is to close a resource that is being transferred via the channel. The following code pattern guarantees that opened resources are closed even if producer, consumer, and/or channel are cancelled. **Resources are never lost**. So no it doesn't return `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and kind explanation!! I think I understand.

Comment: Cool, would be awesome if you can tick it as the correct answer to help others if they need a definition to that topic too! :) Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for how I can tick this answer as the answer. (I'm new to Stack Overflow)